# Google nest wifi and wifi repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mesh-networking

I am trying to setup a mesh network in a large house with concrete walls. Is it possible to put wifi repeaters between the google nest wifi points to get a better range? The setup would be, nest router -> repeater -> nest AP.

It seems to me that the mesh network does always prefer to connect to the router, even if the signal is really bad. And even though I have an additional AP with excellent signal strength that it could connect to.

Just wondered if I could put a repeater in between, so I can extend/improve the signal to the nest point? Anyone have experience with a setup like this, and if so, what sort of hardware did you use?

Answer (score 2):

I have a Nest here. It is just a Wireless device and connects in an ordinary way. So if you insert a repeater and other devices work, then so also will the Nest work. If other devices do not readily see the repeater, then the Nest will not either.

Comment: I know there will be a small impact on performance, but are there other downsides in doing it this way? And if the repeater has a much stronger signal, will the nest AP connect to it (and not to the weaker router signal)?

Comment: That is more difficult to answer. It should connect to the strongest point. I do not know of any other downside based on my own nest unit.